# Passing a variable over to a private npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I've created a private npm package which I can run in my other apps using this code in the html:

```
<app-header-name></app-header-name>
```

This is the code in the npm package it runs:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-name',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public blob: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.blob);
  }
}
```

And this is the html code in the npm package:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    Click the button to download the template
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I pass over a variable from my app to go into the variable blob in the npm package? I have tried the following, which just console logged 'undefined':

```
<app-header-name blob="bazinga"></app-header-name>
```

Also, is there a way to pass data back from the npm package? For example, it will take in the string blob variable, then add another word to it and pass it back to the main app?

Comment: <app-header-name> is a angular component or a custom element web component?

Comment: @abhishek khandait It's an angular component I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a input in your component.

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-name',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() blob: any;

  @Output() somethingOut = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.blob);
  }

  sendToParent() {
    this.somethingOut.emit({ data: 'Hello from child component '});
  }
}
```

passing in a string

```html
<app-header-name blob="bazinga"></app-header-name>
```

passing in a variable from the parent

```html
<app-header-name [blob]="someVarOnTheParent"></app-header-name>
```

passing in and out a variables
the parent component will need a function to receive the data.
Notice the `$event` is needed since the child is passing data

```html
<app-header-name [blob]="someVarOnTheParent" (somethingOut)="parentFunc($event)"></app-header-name>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I also ask, if I have a variable on the npm package component, how do I pass that back to the main app (parent)? I was thinking of having a button on the component, and when pressed it sends data back to the parent app. Is that possible?

Comment: Use `@Output` if you need that. If its the same property you can two way data bind the existing property: https://ofirrifo.medium.com/custom-angular-component-using-two-way-data-binding-aka-banana-in-a-box-syntax-9eb06b8cfb09

Comment: @Marcus Cantu Thank you. I would be sending back a different variable. But how would I receive the data back in the parent app? Currently I am just referencing it in the html with this - <app-header-name blob="bazinga"></app-header-name> - Do I add something to the component file to receive it? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you have to add something special: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs. There are the docs you will need for that but basically it would look like this: 

Parent: `<app-header-name blob="bazinga" (ARBITRARY_OUTPUT_NAME)="functionToCall($event)"></app-header-name>`

Child:
`...
class HeaderComponent {
....
@Input() blob: any; // dont use any.....
@Output() ARBITRARY_OUTPUT_NAME= new EventEmitter<PROP_TYPE_HERE>();
...

someFunction(){
this.ARBITRARY_OUTPUT_NAME.emit(value);
}
}`

Its hard to format this correctly in a comment but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I have update my answer with a output option as well.